# How do I trigger a function when the time reaches a specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a javascript function when the time reaches, say, 3:00 PM.

The time will be assigned dynamically. So is there any javascript function to achieve that??

Comment: You want to trigger it exactly at 3:00pm, or check at specific intervals if 3:00pm has been passed?

Comment: Say like I want to trigger the function at exactly 3:00PM everyday.. something like an alarm. (Although, the time will be assigned dynamically later on)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to calculate the difference between the current time and the target time and use [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) with that value.

For example, depending on how your target browsers parse dates, you could do the following:

```
function alert3pm() {
  alert("It's 3PM!");
}
var timeAt3pm = new Date("1/31/2011 03:00:00 PM").getTime()
  , timeNow = new Date().getTime()
  , offsetMillis = timeAt3pm - timeNow;
setTimeout(alert3pm, offsetMillis);
```

Or rather, instead of parsing a date (since that's really inconsistent between browsers) you could do something like this:

```
function getTimeAtHour(hour) {
  var t = new Date();
  t.setHours(hour);
  t.setMinutes(0);
  t.setSeconds(0);
  t.setMilliseconds(0);
  return t;
}
```

Comment: No difference calculation needed for this one, there's no time period involved.

Comment: Sure there is, setTimeout takes a time period to wait (in ms) and that time period should be the difference between now and the "alarm" time.

Comment: Unusual syntax for declaring a function - perhaps for example purposes, using the more standard `function alert3pm(){}` might be clearer?

Comment: @Basiclife: A JavaScript user should rather be familiar with both... and I'm not sure if either of them qualifies as "more standard" nowadays.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen I understand that both are equally valid but since the OP isn't aware of how to use `SetTimeout()` to wait until a specified time, it's unlikely he's familiar with alternate techniques for defining functions. I wasn't trying to start a syntax war but I do believe that most JS tutorials tend to use the `function Name(){}` syntax as it's closer to the implementation used in other languages. I was simply trying to make the answer easier to understand for the OP. I'm sorry if you don't agree.