# Redirect to Another Webpage at a Specific Time

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm using a web webpage to display digital signage. Once loaded, I need the webpage to wait until 10am and then automatically redirect to another webpage. Could this be done with JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854753/how-do-i-trigger-a-function-when-the-time-reaches-a-specific-time seems to have your answer, just replace the alert with a `document.location = somewhere`

Comment: Yes it can be done. What have you tried so far?