# Realtime highlighting of a table row at a specific time in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm working on a nursery management application, I have a children's table (**childrens**) in my postgres database like this :

| id_child | first_name | last_name | time_to_take_medicine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kids1 | kids1_last_name | 2022-07-26 11:30 |
| 2 | kids2 | kids2_last_name | 2022-07-26 12:30 |
| 3 | kids3 | kids3_last_name | 2022-07-26 14:00 |

I fill this html table below from **childrens** table from database using controller:

```html
<table class="table" id="timeTable">
  <thead>
    <th>first name</th>
    <th>last name</th>
    <th>time to take medicine</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>kids1</td>
      <td>kids1_last_name</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2022-07-26 11:30</td>
 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>kids2</td>
      <td>kids2_last_name</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2022-07-26 12:30</td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>kids3</td>
      <td>kids3_last_name</td>
      <td class="dateRowEnd">2022-07-26 14:00</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When it's time to take medicine of any kids I want to highlight the specific row for 30 seconds without refreshing the browser, how can I do that?

Comment: First, just a 30 second highlight? I’d honestly pop up a modal or something obtrusive and obvious. But to your problem, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854788/231316

Comment: Chris Haas: 30 second highlight  or pop up modal ... , I want any thing to remind me the time to take medicine for this kid is coming.